# Why does pandas parse dates when parse_dates=False

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This may be a feature, but it seems a bit odd. If I have an Excel workbook with one sheet which has one column with 'Date' in A1 and 2015-12-15 in A2 and the column is formatted as 'Date' in Excel, then the following

```
ex=pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
sheet = ex.parse('Sheet1',parse_dates=False)
sheet.dtypes
```

returns

```
Date    datetime64[ns]
```

Why does pandas parse the date when parse_dates=False?

Comment: I think this is a typo in the docs as I think that pandas uses an external library to sniff the dtypes so whatever type was saved in the original excel sheet will be used, can you try with dates stored as str and see if you get the same result. So in a nutshell I think that `parse_dates` does nothing

Comment: @EdChum is correct. Fixed [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11870) to raise when `parse_dates` is passed